# MISSING_TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT_ERROR in Google APIs in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am following this guide in trying to integrate Google APIs with a Rails project: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby

When attempted to run the resulting code, I get:

```
RuntimeError: Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present.
    from /Users/nickbarone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/googleauth-0.6.7/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:100:in `from_hash'
    from /Users/nickbarone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/googleauth-0.6.7/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:85:in `block in from_file'
    from /Users/nickbarone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/googleauth-0.6.7/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:82:in `open'
    from /Users/nickbarone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/googleauth-0.6.7/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:82:in `from_file'
```

which is the `MISSING_TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT_ERROR` error. This is the code block that raises it:

```
  # Constructs a Client ID from a previously loaded JSON file. The hash
  # structure should
  # match the expected JSON format.
  #
  # @param [hash] config
  #  Parsed contents of the JSON file
  # @return [Google::Auth::ClientID]
  def self.from_hash(config)
    raise 'Hash can not be nil.' if config.nil?
    raw_detail = config[INSTALLED_APP] || config[WEB_APP]
    raise MISSING_TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT_ERROR if raw_detail.nil?
    ClientId.new(raw_detail[CLIENT_ID], raw_detail[CLIENT_SECRET])
  end
```

It's... unclear, how to resolve this issue. I haven't been able to establish what value is expected here - the app being connected to? The browser to be used to do the next part of the authentication process? It's also not clear how to set this value - or, given that this script is supposed to work within straight IRB - what in Rails is causing it to be unset.

Ideas? Links? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The problem was that I was accidentally using the credentials for a service account instead of a OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.

In Google Cloud Platform you want to go to: APIs & Services -> OAuth 2.0 Client ID -> Click 'Download JSON' at the top. This is the credentials.json you want to use for the gem 'google-api-client'.

The error is specifically looking for the "installed" JSON key in `credentials.json`. Service accounts don't have that JSON key (and are for a different purpose).

Once I updated it with the proper `credentials.json` I was able to continue on.

Answer (score -1):

You have probably already downloaded `credentials.json` as described in the guide. That file contains the information like:

```
{ 
  "installed": {
    "client_id": ...,
    "client_secret": ...,
    ...
  }
}
```

If you see the full file from the version of the gem you are using: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/v0.6.7/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb you see that config is loaded from file and that location is defined where you call:

```
client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
```

So you need to make sure you define CREDENTIALS_PATH somewhere and that should be the path to credentials.json file. (ex: `Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('/config/credentials.json'`)

I hope this gives you enough information to resolve your issue!

Comment: Thanks, but absolutely does not help. The usage code that I have is already doing that.

Comment: Maybe you can share that code and structure of your json - without values?

Comment: I am following this guide in trying to integrate Google APIs with a Rails project: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby

Comment: It is literally that code copy-pasted into a Rails console.

Comment: Possible issue could be the fact that you are using different gem than defined in the guide: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby/tree/v0.6.7 instead of https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client

I see that from the error stack: 
`...googleauth-0.6.7/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:100:in `from_hash'`

Edit: I bet they are quite similar but better follow the installation guide of the gem you are using.

Comment: Good spot! I'll see if that helps, there are definitely other gems in this project that could be causing that. Thanks!